# FEN diagram reader breaking on an answer

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

This is in regard to the only answer for [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/which-chess-position-requires-the-most-moves-to-reach).

Upon scrolling back on the FEN reader and then clicking on a specific move in the reader leads to this weird interaction where some pieces just break in terms of positioning.

[image]

Is this a known issue?

[image]

Comment: Some obvious s/w engineering questions. 1) Is it repeatable? 2) Is there an exact sequence of operations which consistently gives the problem? If so please give the *exact* sequence. 3) Is this device independent?

Comment: 1) yes, 2) scroll upwards on the move order and select a specific move. 3) it's not browser independant but I can't test on another device. Any fast series of moves changing combined with a selection caused the issue

Comment: @BrianTowers In my experience with posting extremely long answers, this is something that only really happens, the pieces flying all across the screen, when you click far too rapidly for the diagram to properly processes the moves. I've used Chrome for some years now. It might technically be a bug, but might not necessarily to fix so much as a PSA could work.